# Uglify existing AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I have an AngularJs app. I made some modification and I would like to uglify it to run on server. I don't really know anything about it. I've read a lot of websites, but I didn't get it work.
NodeJs is also installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uglify your app with the modifications and deploy to the server again. That's the correct way to go about this as opposed to doing anything on the server.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: There's not enough here to give you a complete answer, but if you had a single JS file, this could be as simple as "npm install uglify-js; uglify-js <file>"

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not a valid SO question, I feel like you don't know where to start so I wanted to offer my help. You should look up [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/). [Here](https://egghead.io/lessons/grunt-minifying-your-output-with-grunt-uglify)'s and example of how to accomplish what you need.